# NHibernate show_sql not showing all inserts

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

`show_sql` shows output for the SQL interactions in the console just fine except for a certain entity type `TimeOff`. Inserts are not showing in the console.

This shows output:

```
var employee = new Employee();
_session.Save(employee);
```

This does not:

```
var timeOff = new TimeOff
{
  Employee = new Employee{Id=1}
};
_session.Save(timeOff);
```

The insert is still happening though.

Here is my fluent-nhibernate config and NUnit startup and teardown:

```
[TestFixture]
public class InsertTests : IDisposable
{
    public InsertTests()
    {
       var cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[0].ConnectionString;

       var config = MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008
            .ConnectionString(cs)
            .ShowSql()
            .FormatSql();

       var sessionFactory = Fluently.Configure()
        .Database(config)
        .Mappings(m =>
            m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<EmployeeMap>())
        .BuildSessionFactory();

       _session = sessionFactory.OpenSession();
    }

    private readonly ISession _session;
    private ITransaction _transaction;

    [SetUp]
    public virtual void SetUp()
    {
      _transaction = _session.BeginTransaction();
    }

    [Test]
    public void no_sql_output()
    {
      var timeOff = new TimeOff
      {
          Employee = new Employee{Id=1}
      };
      _session.Save(timeOff);
    }

    [Test]
    public void shows_sql_output()
    {
       var employee = new Employee();
     
       _session.Save(employee);
    }

    [TearDown]
    public virtual void TearDown()
    {
      //_transaction.Rollback();
      _transaction.Commit();
    }    
}
```

And here are my related maps:

```
public class TimeOffMap : ClassMap<TimeOff>
{
    public TimeOffMap()
    {
        Table("timeoff");

        Id(x => x.Id).Column("timeoff_Id").GeneratedBy.Guid();

        References(x => x.Employee);
     }
 }
 
 
public class EmployeeMap : ClassMap<Employee>
{
    public EmployeeMap()
    {
        Table("employees");

        Id(x => x.Id).Column("employee_id").GeneratedBy.Native();

        HasMany(x => x.TimeOff)
            .Cascade.All()
            .Inverse()
            .KeyColumn("employee_id");
     }
 }
```

The only difference between the two maps is TimeOff has a Guid Id and Employee has an Int. If I insert an Employee and TimeOff in the same transaction, only the Employee Insert shows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference here is that `TimeOff` entity actual DB save is deferred and happens only on transaction commit(which is test  tear down `TearDown` method in your case) or explicit `_session.Flush` call . So I believe that's why you don't see it in test case method `can_add_timeoff` output.

Comment: If I use an `int` ID based entity, it works and shows output though. See my updated tests. I'm going to try mixing `Flush()` in the tests, see if that makes a difference.

Comment: It's not about `int` it's about mapping. Your `int` ID is DB generated and `TimeOff` ID is generated in code. DB generated identifiers (native, identity,...) are saved right away when `session.Save` is called. And generated by code (guid, assigned, ...) are actually saved only when session is flushed (and it's transaction commit in your case and it's out of scope of your test). So yes you should move transaction commit in scope of your test method to see output